# How to add print OP in TensorFlow layer(GRU)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, printing, operation

I add print OP in GRU source code, and want to debug the input of GRU , and also want to debug with some operation inside GRU, But this print nothing.
Dose tf.print don't work inside this source code of GRU.
I hope someone can give me some suggesstion.
Thank you very much!

```py
  def call(self, inputs, state):
    """Gated recurrent unit (GRU) with nunits cells."""

    import tensorflow as tf
    print_GRU =  tf.print(inputs) #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   add print OP HERE
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_GRU]):
        gate_inputs = math_ops.matmul(
            array_ops.concat([inputs, state], 1), self._gate_kernel)

    # gate_inputs = math_ops.matmul(
    #     array_ops.concat([inputs, state], 1), self._gate_kernel)
    gate_inputs = nn_ops.bias_add(gate_inputs, self._gate_bias)

    value = math_ops.sigmoid(gate_inputs)
    r, u = array_ops.split(value=value, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)

    r_state = r * state

    candidate = math_ops.matmul(
        array_ops.concat([inputs, r_state], 1), self._candidate_kernel)
    candidate = nn_ops.bias_add(candidate, self._candidate_bias)

    c = self._activation(candidate)
    new_h = u * state + (1 - u) * c
    return new_h, new_h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `call`, use this line:

```
tf.py_function(func=tf.print, inp=[inputs], Tout=[])
```